# I need help the first object is saved undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

well, in the code you can see that when the first object is saved, the id comes out undefined and then the other objects start to come out fine, I was thinking about it but I can't fix it, the problem is in the save() function in the part that pushes the newProduct does anyone realize what the problem is?

```js
const fs = require("fs");

class Container {
    constructor(fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    async createEmptyFile() {
        fs.writeFile(this.fileName, "[]", (error) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            } else {
                console.log(`File ${this.fileName} was created`);
            }
        });
    }

    async readFile() {
        try {
            const data = await fs.promises.readFile(this.fileName, 'utf-8');
            return JSON.parse(data);
        } catch (error) {
            if (error) {
                this.createEmptyFile();
            } else {
                console.log(`Error Code: ${error} | There was an unexpected error when trying to read ${this.fileName}`);
            }
        }
    }

    async save(title, price, thumbnail) {
        try {
            const data = await this.readFile();
            const newProduct = {
                title,
                price,
                thumbnail,
                id: data.length + 1
            }
            data.push(newProduct);
            await fs.promises.writeFile(this.fileName, JSON.stringify(data));
            return newProduct.id;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error Code: ${error.code} | There was an error when trying to save an element`);
        }
    }

    

    
}

const container = new Container("products.json");

const main = async () => {
    const id1 = await container.save(
        "Regla",
        75,
        "https://rfmayorista.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/REGLA-ECONM_15-CM.-600x600.jpg"
    );
    const id2 = await container.save(
        "Goma",
        50,
        "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/rubber-eraser-pencil-ink-pen-260nw-656520052.jpg"
    );
    const id3 = await container.save(
        "Lapicera",
        100,
        "https://aldina.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/bic-cristal-trazo-fino-azul-1.jpg"
    );

    console.log(id1, id2, id3); 
};

main();
```

From already thank you very much

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work.

Comment: @user1599011 it doesn't work because it's a nodeJS file, not a browser JS file. But snippets are often useful if you want to copy the code into your answer.

Comment: as @Andy says it is a nodeJS file, I put the snippet so that the code looks good

Answer (score 0):

In the `readFile` method you need to return something on the `catch` statement in order to get consistent return values

```js
async readFile() {
        try {
            const data = await fs.promises.readFile(this.fileName, 'utf-8');
            return JSON.parse(data);
        } catch (error) {
            if (error) {
                this.createEmptyFile();
            } else {
                console.log(`Error Code: ${error} | There was an unexpected error when trying to read ${this.fileName}`);
            }
            // returns [] because this seems to be the default value for the file in createEmptyFile
            return []; // Add this line 
        }
    }
```

What happens is practice is: the file doesn't exist, the `try` statement fails, then the `catch` statement and the function don't return anything thus `undefined`.